# History pushed state is not in standalone location.hash or location.href but is in Location object itself

Tags: javascript, html, pushstate, html5-history

Can anyone explain this behavior? I push history state using `history.pushState(null, null, '#test');`. Then when trying to get state URL in the listener function (didn't find a better way how to listen to pushState changes) using `console.log(window.location.hash)`, it returns empty string, `#test` hash. `console.log(window.location.href)` returns whole URL without hash `#test` too but `console.log(window.location)` returns `Location` object where the hash is in both `href` and `hash` properties. Why is that and how can I get the URL of pushed state?

```
        (function(history){
            var pushState = history.pushState;
            history.pushState = function(state) {
                if (typeof history.onpushstate == "function") {
                    history.onpushstate({state: state});
                }
                console.log(window.location.hash);
                console.log(window.location.href);
                console.log(window.location);
                return pushState.apply(history, arguments);
            }
        })(window.history);

        history.pushState(null, null, '#test');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are logging the variables before you actually set the new state. The reason you can see the updated properties in the object, because it logs a reference to the object, rather than a copy of the object when it was logged. Your monkey patch does not call the original `pushState` function until this line.

```
return pushState.apply(history, arguments);
```

To work around this, you could simple call the function before logging, then return the response afterwards.

```
(function(history){
    var pushState = history.pushState;
    history.pushState = function(state) {
        if (typeof history.onpushstate == "function") {
            history.onpushstate({state: state});
        }
        var r = pushState.apply(history, arguments);
        console.log(window.location.hash);
        console.log(window.location.href);
        console.log(window.location);
        return r;
    }
})(window.history);

history.pushState(null, null, '#test');
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that. But why is it in `window.location` and not `window.location.hash` before applying is still a bit of a mystery to me...

Comment: @simPod When you `console.log` an object, it is a live reference to the object. If the properties are changed after logging, when you inspect the object you will see the updated properties.